# _.filter() and new Function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filter

This is what I have, please let me know how to get the filter to properly filter through the dictionary using the new `Function` process.

```
let _ = require('underscore');
let inventory = [{'id':1, 'color':'red', 'size':'large'}, {'id':2, 'color':'orange', 'size':'small'}, {'id':3, 'color':'orange', 'size':'large'}, {'id':4, 'color':'red', 'size':'small'}, {'id':1, 'color':'orange', 'size':'small'}];

let criteria = 'size==large, id>2';

let data = _.filter(data, new Function(criteria));
```

This function was meant to return `"{'id':3, 'color':'orange', 'size':'large'}"` only, not any of the other key-value pairs, but instead I just keep getting errors about how `large` is not defined. If criteria is `"id>2"`, then the error says that 2 is not defined

Comment: I accidentally included data in the filter, what I meant was...                                                         
                                                                                                                                                        let data = _.filter(inventory, new Function(criteria) );

Answer (score 1):

A `Function` object requires a set of arguments and a function body. What we can do is the following:

```
let data = _.filter(inventory, new Function('x', 'return x.size === "large" && x.id > 2'));
```

I tried out objects destructuring as well, and it worked:

```
let data = _.filter(inventory, new Function('{size, id}', 'return size === "large" && id > 2'));
```

While these do work, It is not recommended to have something like this in your code. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> Note: Using the Function constructor to create functions is not recommended since it needs the function body as a string which may prevent some JS engine optimizations and can also cause other problems.

This is way better, in my opinion:

```
let data = _.filter(inventory, x => x.size === "large" && x.id > 2);
```